# Errors in update checking script (cause: repositories not available)

Tags: 14.04, bash, updates, webserver

I have a scripts that tests if updates on my 14.04 server are available, and send me a text message if that happens.

The bash script begins with:

```
IFS=';' read updates security_updates < <(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1)
```

And then tests:

```
if [ $updates != 0 ];
then
…
```

and later on:

```
if [ $security_updates != 0 ];
then
```

The issue is `updates` and `security_updates` should both contain the number of updates like `3` and `1`. But sometimes, the first command fails and returns:

```
E: Unknown Error: '<class 'SystemError'>' (E:Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net_ftp.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_universe_i18n_Translation-en - open (2: No such file or directory), E:Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net_ftp.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_restricted_i18n_Translation-en - open (2: No such file or directory), E:Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net_ftp.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en - open (2: No such file or directory), E:Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net_ftp.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en - open (2: No such file or directory), E:Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net_ftp.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages - open (2: No such file or directory), E:Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/ubuntu.mirrors.ov
h.net_ftp.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_universe_binary-i386_Packages - open (2: No such file or directory),
```

As a result my script fails and cron sends me an e-mail.
How can I test for errors before testing the content of the variables themselves? `$?` doesn't help…

EDIT:

I also tried:

```
s="${updates}"
size=${#s}
if [[ $size > 3 ]] ;then
  echo "DATA TOO LARGE";
  exit;
fi
```

Most of the time, this fails to detect the string is too long… I sometimes get data too large, sometimes I get the errors

`line 25: [: too many arguments`  => that's the line of the first `if` statement
`line 38: [: !=: unary operator expected` => that's the line of the second `if` statement

Comment: Try not to redirect stderr and then `$?`.  (Just a hunch, not tested, and therefore a comment)

Comment: @Fabby Thank you for your reply. It didn't work. I also added the code above (see edit) to check for the length of the string (there can't be more than 999 updates at once !) and it fails to even see the string is too long (most of the time).

Comment: Beyond me.  But I've upvoted your question and added "bash" to the tags... That should attract some more knowledgeable people then me!  ;-)